# Firebase admin sdk on Tomcat servlet

Tags: java, firebase, tomcat, firebase-admin

What I want to do:

[image: What I want to do]

I am using tomcat v8.5.3 and Firebase Admin SDK v6.8.1 for java.

Above image is what I want to do.

But I have a problem with request forwarding from servlet to jsp

this is the doPost code of servletA.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    if(FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) {
        FirebaseOptions options = (FirebaseOptions)getServletContext().getAttribute("options");
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    }

    dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/b.jsp");

    try {
        process(request, response);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot item: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                couponList.add(item.getValue(CouponItem.class));
            }

            request.setAttribute("bodyObject", requestBody);
            try {
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            } catch (ServletException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});
}


protected void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws IOException, ParseException{

    initMember();

    //requestBodyString = getBody(request);
    requestBodyString = (String) request.getParameter("body");

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(requestBodyString);

    convert(jobj, requestBody);

    Ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Coupon").child(requestBody.getRequestId());

}
```

In the onDataChange of ValueEventListener, dispatcher forward does not work.

I found that Daemon Thread is changed when code is Ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent from

```
Daemon Thread [http-nio-8080-exec-5] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 67 in ServletA))    
owns: NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper  (id=426)    
ServletA.doPost(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 67   
ServletA(HttpServlet).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 660    
ServletA(HttpServlet).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 741    
ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 231  
ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 166  
WsFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 52    
ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 193  
ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 166  
StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 199    
StandardContextValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 96 
NonLoginAuthenticator(AuthenticatorBase).invoke(Request, Response) line: 493    
StandardHostValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 137   
ErrorReportValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 81 
AccessLogValve(AbstractAccessLogValve).invoke(Request, Response) line: 660  
StandardEngineValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 87  
CoyoteAdapter.service(Request, Response) line: 343  
Http11Processor.service(SocketWrapperBase<?>) line: 798 
Http11Processor(AbstractProcessorLight).process(SocketWrapperBase<?>, SocketEvent) line: 66 
AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler<S>.process(SocketWrapperBase<S>, SocketEvent) line: 808  
NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun() line: 1498  
NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor(SocketProcessorBase<S>).run() line: 49  
ThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor).runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1149  
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 624   
TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run() line: 61  
TaskThread(Thread).run() line: 748
```

to

```
Daemon Thread [firebase-database-event-target] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 87 in ServletA$1))    
ServletA$1.onDataChange(DataSnapshot) line: 87  
Query$1.onDataChange(DataSnapshot) line: 182    
ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(DataEvent) line: 77    
DataEvent.fire() line: 65   
EventRaiser$1.run() line: 55    
Executors$RunnableAdapter<T>.call() line: 511   
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask<V>(FutureTask<V>).run() line: 266   
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask<V>.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask) line: 180    
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask<V>.run() line: 293  
FirebaseScheduledExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor).runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1149   
ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 624   
Thread.run() line: 748
```

I think I don't have enough experience with Tomcat and Java for solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database event listener runs on a separate thread. You cannot perform a forward or any response action on it, since the request thread exits immediately after your call to `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`. You need to somehow halt the request thread from exiting until your event listener is executed. A `CountDownLatch` is probably the easiest way.

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    latch.countDown();
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    latch.countDown();
  }
});

// Wait for the callbacks to fire
latch.await();

// Send response
```